# Powershell How to generate multiple combinations

Tags: arrays, powershell, generate-series

I'm trying to create a function that compares if the beginning of an input string matches one of the possibilities generated from the combinations in multiple `System.Arrays`. The result of this function will be a returned object with the input `GroupName`we received and if it's a valid name or not `$true/$false`.

**Array1:**

```
Country
-------
BEL
NLD
```

**Array2:**

```
Color
----
Green
Red
```

**Array3:**

```
Type            Object
----            ------
Fruit           Banana
Veggetables     Aubergine
Fruit           Appel
Veggetables     Carrot
Fruit           Peer
```

**Generated list in the function to check validity against:**

```
BEL Green-Fruit-Banana
BEL Green-Fruit-Appel
BEL Green-Fruit-Peer
BEL Green-Vegetables-Aubergine
BEL Green-Vegetables-Carrot
NLD Green-Fruit-Banana
NLD Green-Fruit-Appel
NLD Green-Fruit-Peer
NLD Green-Vegetables-Aubergine
NLD Green-Vegetables-Carrot
BEL Red-Fruit-Banana
BEL Red-Fruit-Appel
BEL Red-Fruit-Peer
BEL Red-Vegetables-Aubergine
BEL Red-Vegetables-Carrot
NLD Red-Fruit-Banana
NLD Red-Fruit-Appel
NLD Red-Fruit-Peer
NLD Red-Vegetables-Aubergine
NLD Red-Vegetables-Carrot
```

The code I have already is to create the object. But I don't know the best way on how to generate this list in the function and fill the value `Valid`.

```
Function Compare-Names {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [string[]]$GroupName
    )
    PROCESS {
        # Generate all options
        <# Fill Valid $true or false here #>

        foreach ($Group in $GroupName) {
            $obj = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property ([ordered] @{
                'GroupName' = $Group;
                'Valid' = $Valid;
            })
        Write-Output $obj
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I realize that you already accepted an answer, but I thought I'd offer an alternative solution. Using a RegEx match against the group name format "Country Color-Type-Object" and the -Contains operator you don't even need to generate the whole list of possible names.

```
Function Compare-Names {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [string[]]$GroupName
    )
    BEGIN {
        $Array1 = "BEL","NLD"|%{[pscustomobject]@{Country=$_}}
        $Array2 = "Green","Red"|%{[pscustomobject]@{Color=$_}}
        $Array3 = ("Fruit","Banana"),("Vegetables","Aubergine"),("Fruit","Appel"),("Vegetables","Carrot"),("Fruit","Peer")|%{[pscustomobject]@{Type=$_[0];Object=$_[1]}}
        [RegEx]$RegEx = "(.+?) (.+?)-(.+?)-(.+?)$"
    }
    PROCESS {
        ForEach($Group in @($GroupName)){
        $NameSplit = $regex.Match($Group) | Select -ExpandProperty Groups
            [PSCustomObject][ordered] @{
                'GroupName' = $Group
                'Valid' = If($Array1.Country -contains $NameSplit[1] -and $Array2.Color -contains $NameSplit[2] -and $Array3.Type -contains $NameSplit[3] -and $Array3.Object -contains $NameSplit[4]){$true}else{$false}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That will output everything piped into it with the GroupName and Valid properties, so if you want to only process things that are valid do something like:

```
"BEL Green-Fruit-Banana",
"BEL Green-Fruit-Appel",
"BEL Green-Fruit-Peer",
"BEL Green-Vegetables-Aubergine",
"BEL Green-Vegetables-Carrot",
"NLD Green-Fruit-Banana",
"BEL Green-Fruit-Grape" | Compare-Names | Where{$_.Valid}
```

That will just output the valid names:

```
GroupName                      Valid
---------                      -----
BEL Green-Fruit-Banana          True
BEL Green-Fruit-Appel           True
BEL Green-Fruit-Peer            True
BEL Green-Vegetables-Aubergine  True
BEL Green-Vegetables-Carrot     True
NLD Green-Fruit-Banana          True
```

This way you can run a report after the fact with `Where{!$_.Valid}` and find out which ones failed and form a list of rejects.

```
GroupName             Valid
---------             -----
BEL Green-Fruit-Grape False
```

Comment: This looks more effective than what I had before. Although my input will be something like `"BEL Green-Fruit-Banana Njam njam"`. So I only need to be sure that the beginning of the string is correct. I'll try it out asap. Thank you for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: The regex to only check the beginning of the string is `[RegEx]$RegEx = "(.+?) (.+?)-(.+?)-(.+?)( .+?)?$"`. What this code doesn't do correctly is saying `Valid=$True` for an invalid combination like for example `BEL Green-Fruit-Carrot`. In this case it should say `Valid=$False` as it's not matching.

Comment: I've combined `Object`and `Type` in one value for `PSCustomObject`, which solved the problem of not being related to each other.

Answer (score 2):

```
$Countries = @('BEL', 'NLD')
$Colors = @('Green', 'Red')
$Objects = @{ 'Fruit' = @('Banana', 'Apple'); 'Vegetable' = @('Aubergine', 'Carrot') }

$countries | %{
    $country = $_

    $Colors | %{
        $color = $_

        $Objects.Keys | %{
            $key = $_
            $values = $Objects.$key

            $values | %{
                $value = $_

                Write-Host "$country $color-$key-$value"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you David. But it's not generating `Aubergine` and `Carrot`. Also the value `$Valid` isn't filled with `$true` or `$false`. Also, the `Objects` in your example is a `System.Object` and not a `System.Array` as in my example. But it's a good base to start from. Thanks man!

Comment: Fixed: a mispell in $Objects.$key (was $Object.$key)

Comment: Awesome! One question I still have, how can i do it if I address the values in the array like this: `$Array3.Type` and `$Array3.Object`? Because Type and Object are the titles of the arrays columns..

Comment: Replace the `$Objects.Keys | % {.....}` part with `$Array3 | % { "$country $color-$($_.Type)-$($_.Object)" }`