# PowerShell Regex match beginning of string

Tags: regex, powershell

There's a regex that does exactly what I want, but I would like it to be able to only check the beginning of the string and don't look at the stuff coming after it.

**Working regex:**

```
[RegEx]$RegEx = "(.+?) (.+?)-(.+?)-(.+?)$"
```

**Failed attempts:**

```
[RegEx]$RegEx = "^((.+?) (.+?)-(.+?)-(.+?))"
[RegEx]$RegEx = "\A(.+?) (.+?)-(.+?)-(.+?)"
```

**Examples:**

```
# Ok:
BEL Green-Fruit-Appel Stuff
BEL Green-Fruit-Appel Other stuff stuff

# Not ok (without anything):
BEL Green-Fruit-Appel
```

[More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199659/powershell-how-to-generate-multiple-combinations/25209228#25209228)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you show some example data?

Comment: A caret `^` should work, e.g.: `"A123" -match "^A.*"` returns `True`. Please can you supply your test-cases

Comment: try this:  [RegEx]$RegEx = "(.+?) (.+?)-(.+?)-(.+?)( .+?)?$"

Comment: Hi Tim, your one works almost a 100% perfect. The only problem left is that it's also accepting `BEL Green-Fruit-Appel` as `$true`, while it should have something after it like `BEL Green-Fruit-Appel Stuff` before it can be `$true`.

Comment: Fixed it my adding a space in between, like so: `[RegEx]$RegEx = "(.+?) (.+?)-(.+?)-(.+?)( .+?) ?$"` Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ditch the `$` and use `^`:

```
C:\PS> 'BEL Green-Fruit-Appel' -match '^(.+?) (.+?)-(.+?)-(.+?)'
True

C:\PS> $matches
Name                           Value
----                           -----
4                              A
3                              Fruit
2                              Green
1                              BEL
0                              BEL Green-Fruit-A
```

The last capture group is just `A` because you are using the non-greedy `?` so it stops after the first char.  If you want the whole word, change the last capture group to `-(\w+)'.

Comment: Good morning Keith, thanks for your reply. I'm afraid it's not really delivering the expecting result, as it's saying `$True` for `BEL Green-Fruit-Appel`, while it should say `$False` because of the missing words behind it (like `BEL Green-Fruit-Appel Njma njam`). This is the only thing that does exactly what I want: `"(.+?) (.+?)-(.+?)( .+?) ?$"` Thanks for the tip on `$matches`, didn't know about this.

Comment: Did a little modification, it's fine now, thank you :)